# Why am I getting org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to learn Mockito on Android and using the mockito-kotlin library by nhaarman.  I'm getting a strange Mockito error that reads:

"org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue: 
'execute' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*"

The strange thing is that I'm **not** stubbing this class. Here's the unit test that's having the problem.

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class PoiListViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    //Mocks
    @Mock lateinit var getPois: GetPois
    @Mock lateinit var mapper: PoiMapper
    @Mock lateinit var observer: Observer<List<Poi_Presentation>>

    // Class being tested
    lateinit var poiListViewModel: PoiListViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        poiListViewModel = PoiListViewModel(getPois,mapper)
    }

    private fun stubMapper(poi_Domain: Poi_Domain, poiPresentation: Poi_Presentation) {
        `when`(mapper.mapToPresentation(poi_Domain)).thenReturn(poiPresentation)
    }

    @Test
    fun fetchAllPoisExecutesUseCaseOnStart(){
        verify(getPois, times(1)).execute(any(), eq(null))
    }

    @Test
    fun poiSubscriberOnNextMapsCorrectly(){
        val poiDomains = TestDataFactory.makePoiDomainList(2)
        val poiPresentations = TestDataFactory.makePoiPresentationList(2)
        stubMapper(poiDomains[0],poiPresentations[0])

        poiListViewModel.getAllPois().observeForever(observer)    
        poiListViewModel.PoiSubscriber().onNext(poiDomains)
        assertEquals(poiListViewModel.getAllPois().value,poiPresentations)
    }
}
```

And here is my class being tested:

```
open class PoiListViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val getPois: GetPois,
        private val mapper: PoiMapper
) : ViewModel() {

    private val poiData: MutableLiveData<List<Poi_Presentation>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
       fetchAllPois()
    }

    fun getAllPois(): LiveData<List<Poi_Presentation>> {
        return poiData
    }

    fun fetchAllPois() {
        getPois.execute(PoiSubscriber())
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        getPois.dispose()
        super.onCleared()
    }

    inner class PoiSubscriber: DisposableObserver<List<Poi_Domain>>(){
        override fun onComplete() {
            Log.i("poiSubscriber: ", "completed")
        }

        override fun onNext(data: List<Poi_Domain>) {
            poiData.postValue(data.map {
                mapper.mapToPresentation(it)
            })
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            Log.e("Obervable error: ", e.localizedMessage )
        }
    }
}
```

It's a short unit test, and you can see that I'm **not** trying to stub execute, so why is Mockito giving me this error?  the execute method does fire when my test class get's created, but I used a mock object (getPois), so the method should do nothing by default correct?  Strangely the error occurs when I attempt to stub another class PoiMapper.  Here's that class:

```
open class PoiMapper @Inject constructor() {
    fun mapToPresentation(domainModel: Poi_Domain): Poi_Presentation {
        return Poi_Presentation(domainModel.id,domainModel.name,domainModel.description,
                domainModel.img_url,domainModel.latitude,domainModel.longitude,domainModel.imgFocalpointX,
                domainModel.imgFocalpointY,domainModel.collection,domainModel.collectionPosition,
                domainModel.release,domainModel.stampText)
    }
}
```

This method does have a return type, so it should not be a part of the problem. I'm hoping someone can explain to me what's going on as I'm stumped.  Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm calling this method in a lambda?